# Linear combination of normal distribution with Slutsky's theorem

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, convergence, central-limit-theorem, slutsky-theorem

Suppose

$$\sqrt{n} (\hat{\beta} - \beta) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0, \sigma^2)$$

Then I know that for some constant $\alpha$ that a linear combination of normal is normal:

$$\sqrt{n} (\alpha\hat{\beta} - \alpha\beta) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0, \sigma^2\alpha^2).$$

Now suppose that $\hat{\alpha} \rightarrow \alpha$, my question is, does

$$\sqrt{n} (\hat{\alpha}\hat{\beta} - \alpha\beta) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0, \sigma^2\alpha^2)$$

by Slutsky's theorem?

Comment: Your first claim is not Slutsky's theorem but the delta method...

Comment: Yes, agreed. But my question is really about the second claim, not the first.

Comment: Slutsky's theorem doesn't apply in this way; you can generally think of it as a type of continuous mapping theorem whereby if $\hat{\theta_n} \stackrel{d}{\to} \theta$ then for an almost everywhere continuous function $g$ $ g(\hat{\theta_n}) \stackrel{d}{\to} g(\theta)$. This form does not apply to your second or first questions.

Comment: Understood. Under what circumstances would my second claim hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is not true.  As a counterexample, let $\alpha = 1$, $\hat{\alpha} = 1 + n^{-1/2}$ (non-random), then $\hat{\alpha} \to \alpha$, but
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}(\hat{\alpha}\hat{\beta} - \alpha\beta) = \sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta} - \beta) + \hat{\beta}, 
\end{align}
which, by Slutsky's theorem (note that $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta} - \beta) \to_d N(0, \sigma^2)$ implies that $\hat{\beta} \to_P \beta$), converges to $N(\beta, \sigma^2)$ in distribution, which is not the same as $N(0, \sigma^2)$ when $\beta \neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. As a follow-up question, what conditions can I put on $\hat{\alpha}$ so that my conjecture is true?

Comment: @Adrian A simple condition you can impose is that $(\hat{\alpha}, \hat{\beta})$ is jointly asympotic normal (i.e., you have a bivariate CLT holds).  You can then use 2D delta-method to get the desired result.  But in general the asympotic variance would not be $\alpha^2\sigma^2$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong can the problem be fixed by giving some little-oh criterion on the rate of convergence of the $\alpha$? Suppose we require $\alpha$ is $o(n^{1/4})$. Is this even well defined for probabilistic convergence? I acknoweldge this is now a different question.